# open-graph-scraper (NodeJs) doesn't return response body with the use of proxy

Tags: node.js, docker, proxy

I am using [open-graph-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper) with proxies as mentioned in the documentation. It works fine with a normal start-up. As an example when I run the node program using
`node server.js`  it returns the result as follows.

```
{ "ogDescription": "Node.js scraper module for Open Graph and Twitter Card info", 
  "ogTitle": "open-graph-scraper", 
  "ogUrl": "https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper", 
  "ogSiteName": "npm", 
  "twitterCard": "summary", 
  "twitterUrl": "https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper", 
  "twitterTitle": "npm: open-graph-scraper", 
  "twitterDescription": "Node.js scraper module for Open Graph and Twitter Card 
    info",
  "ogImage": { "URL": 
  "https://static.npmjs.com/338e4905a2684ca96e08c7780fc68412.png", "width": null, 
  "height": null, "type": "png" }, "ogLocale": "en", "ogDate": "2021-08- 
  10T00:29:36.453Z", "charset": "utf8", "requestUrl": 
  "https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper", "success": true 
}
```

But when I try to run the same program using the docker container the result looks like this. Basically, it doesn't have a response body.

```
{ "charset": null, 
  "requestUrl": "https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper", 
  "success": true 
}
```

This is my docker file.

```
FROM node:14

FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000 22 3128

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "server.js" ]
```

This is the command I used to run the docker image.

```
docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 <container-name>
```

I would be much thankful if anyone can give a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue. It was basically with the PM2 configurations in the docker file. Following the docker file fixed the issue.

```
FROM node:14
FROM keymetrics/pm2:14-alpine


WORKDIR /usr/src/app


COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install


COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000 22 3128
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "server.js" ]
```